# At what frequency will the reactance of a 200mH inductor will be 5kΩ?

Tags: inductance, reactance

I'm doing practice exam questions, I have no idea what formula applies to this question. I know Xl = 2πf*L, but the question is asking for the frequency, how can I complete this when the formula for angular velocity relies on the value of the frequency. I'm assuming I'm way off the mark. And it'll probably be something as simple.

Comment: Angular frequency, \$\omega=2\pi f\$, where \$f\$ is the frequency in Hz.

Comment: You are given L and Xl, and you presumably know what 2 and pi are. What's left? Rearrange and solve to find f.

Comment: What does the f in the formula represent?

Answer (score 2):

> At what frequency will the reactance of a 200mH inductor will be 5kΩ?

This is *really basic*.  Go back and re-read the section in your course material on inductors.  Surely you will find the formula

Ω = ωL

where Ω is the impedance magnitude in Ohms, ω the frequency applied to the inductor in radians/second, and L the inductance in Henries.

The rest is just plugging in the numbers.